# How to structure the code using custom hook

Tags: reactjs

I want to split my code in 2 files.
The initial file is: https://codesandbox.io/s/ixq97,

Now i tried to split the code in 2 files. One part of the code is located in `test.js` and another in `index.js`.
For this i did: https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-selection-ant-design-demo-s2x8b?file=/index.js
There i created useTest too keep all code  together,

```js
useTest()
```

but now i hove to pass as a prop: `rowSelection={rowSelection}` in `Table` component, but i can't. How to split these 2 parts of codes using a hook? Or exists another solution to do this?

Comment: The file 'test.js' is empty.

Comment: @cyck, i check and  will solve

Comment: Also, would be easier if you clearly state what you're trying to achieve with such code, as well.

Comment: @cyck, it works? My target is to structure the code. To keep the code what is related to `select` feature in one file and the `table` component to keep clear. Now i want to store all data from test as a file and to import in index js, and only there to use.

Comment: @cyck, please, let me know if my target is clear and if all code appears now. Thanks

Comment: @Asking looks like you forgot to return `rowSelection` from the hook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there! You just missed the return. Never forget that `React` is just a library for JavaScript, so, everything that you right in React is plain JavaScript.

Given that, your `useTest` is just a function and if you need to get some value out of it, you'll need a simple return. For your case would be

```
export function useTest() {
    // ...
    return { rowSelection };
}
```